# Guilloché security printing -- can it be cracked?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, plane-curves, pattern-recognition

Money uses [Security printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_printing), and often uses [Guilloché patterns](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/13-Guilloche%20Patterns/mathgames_02_09_04.html).  These curves are inscribed by wheels on wheels on wheels, ten wheels deep in some cases.

For example, the back of the US $1 bill has many guilloché curves.  Virtually all world currency uses these patterns.  Can they be cracked?  Can someone replicate parts of the curves on the currency of their choice?

Comment: Nice topic. What would it mean to crack? Are we given a sufficient number of points in the curve with enough precision? Are we given all the points in the curve? We could ask what is the maximum number of wheels used in a curve that can be determined by giving $n$ points on it. Is the question about how to reproduce them in practice?

Comment: A person could sample the curves however they liked.  Then, they should be able to overlay a sample of their chosen currency with programmatically generated curves which exactly cover the curves in the sample.

Comment: In order to get a problem well formulated one should impose certain restrictions, and make clear the issue of the precision. Otherwise you can get trivial (but useless) answers like: *If I can sample all the points in the curve with infinite precision then I can draw the curve. You don't even need to find the wheel configuration.* So, problems with more interesting solutions, would limit the number of samples, would allow error margin in the solution if the samples have an approximation error. Maybe the problem can require certain bounds in these errors.

Comment: My thought is that all of these curves can be reduced to 10 or so values all under 1000.  Then, different sets could be plugged into the code to replicate portions of twenty different currencies.  That would definitely show that guilloché patterns were solvable.